# How to upload vhd size of more than 1 TB in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In May 2017 Azure Rm is Supporting more than 1 TB disk size i have an vhd that size is more than 1 TB how to upload it in Azure Resource Manager Storage Account?

Comment: so what have you tried? i would imagine all the regular ways work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to upload it in Azure Resource Manager Storage Account?

You could upload it throw Powershell. Here is a sample code.

```
$rgName = "myResourceGroup"
$urlOfUploadedVhd = "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myUploadedVHD.vhd"
Add-AzureRmVhd -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Destination $urlOfUploadedVhd `
    -LocalFilePath "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Virtual hard disks\myVHD.vhd"
```

If you want to use this VHD to create a VM, you also need to prepare the VHD for VM. Here are steps to prepare the VHD.

1. [Prepare a Windows VHD to upload to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json). Do not generalize the VM using Sysprep.
2. Remove any guest virtualization tools and agents that are installed on the VM (i.e. VMware tools).
3. Ensure the VM is configured to pull its IP address and DNS settings via DHCP. This ensures that the server obtains an IP address within the VNet when it starts up.

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[Upload a specialized VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized#option-1-upload-a-specialized-vhd)

**Edit 2017/6/22**

To upload VHD file of more than 1TB as page blob or unmanaged disks, we need to use the latest released toolsets.

```
| Azure Tools       | Supported Versions                                 |
| -------------     |:-------------:                                     |
| Azure Powershell  | Version number v4.1.0 – June 2017 Release or above |
| Azure CLI v1      | Version number 0.10.13 – May 2017 Release or above |   
| AzCopy            | Version number v6.1.0 – June 2017 Release or above |
```

Reference. [New Disk Sizes - both managed and unmanaged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-faq-for-disks#new-disk-sizes---both-managed-and-unmanaged)

Comment: I finally find the answer in azure ARM we can't upload a vhd that size more than 1 TB is currently not supported

Comment: Reference link:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-azure-s-largest-disk-sizes/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer.

Comment: I updated my reply to provide the latest release toolsets which support upload VHD file of more than 1TB.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.